# Application does not start because of permissions denied (deluge-web)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, deluge

I am trying to run deluge-web service under the deluge and getting permissions denied errors.

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u deluge /usr/bin/deluge-web
[sudo] password for myuser:
[ERROR   ] 16:12:23 common:167 Unable to use default config directory, exiting... ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/.config/deluge')
```

Ownership and permissions on the folder:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /home/myuser/.config/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 6 deluge deluge 4096 Oct 14 14:02 deluge
```

I've also tried to add "deluge" user to the "sudo" group (silly, but I really do not know how to solve that) and still getting the same error:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo usermod -a -G sudo deluge
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u deluge /usr/bin/deluge-web
[ERROR   ] 16:17:30 common:167 Unable to use default config directory, exiting... ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/.config/deluge')
```

However if I run it under "myuser" then it works well:

```
sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/deluge-web
```

What should I do?

UPDATE:
This is my init script:

```
# deluge-web - Deluge Web UI
#
# The Web UI component of Deluge BitTorrent client, connects to deluged and
# provides a web application interface for users. Default url: http://localhost:8112

description "Deluge Web UI"
author "Deluge Team"

start on started deluged
stop on stopping deluged

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

env uid=deluge
env gid=deluge
env umask=027

exec start-stop-daemon -S -c $uid:$gid -k $umask -x /usr/bin/deluge-web -l /var/log/deluge/deluge-web.conf -L warning
```

Comment: Which are the permission of `~/.config`? `ls -lad ~/.config`. Did you try to change the `uid` `guid` and `umask` in `/etc/init/deluge-web.conf`?

Comment: Changed ownership of the ~/.config directory and it worked. What umask do I need to use in the init config?

Comment: Following your needs or moods :-) (See below in the answer and in the reference).

Answer (score 1):

With

> Permission denied: '/home/myuser/.config/deluge'

the program says that it cannot access to the directory.
Check the permission for the father directory `/home/myuser/.config` with

```
ls -lad /home/myuser/.config
```

and change them if needed.

Below is an explanation of how you can manage access and permission of files downloaded through Deluge (umask parameter):

> - 007 grants full access to the user and members of the group Deluge is running as (in this case Deluge) and prevents access from all other accounts.
> - 022 grants full access to the user Deluge is running as and only read access to other accounts.
> - 000 grants full access to all accounts.

Further lectures

- [Install deluge web interface on Ubuntu](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-deluge-web-interface-on-ubuntu-1204/1/)
- [Upstart not starting deluge](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=47951) different solution proposed

Comment: I've modified the question. Added the init script. Changed umask from 027 to 000  and it doesn't start anyway

Comment: From the second link they propose "In the end i just let it use `/var/lib/deluge` as its config directory.", in the second iain  created a user deluge,  `env uid=deluge`, `env gid=deluge` ,`env umask=000` in the config file and `exec start-stop-daemon -S -c $uid:$gid -k $umask -x /usr/bin/deluge-web`... BTW Did you restart it to allow it to notice the changes? (`sudo stop deluge` and `sudo stop deluge-web` followed by `sudo start deluge`) ...?

Comment: did not understand you well. However I do not know how to specify /var/lib/deluge as config directory ... I've changed the umask=000 and rebooted the machine. It did not help